# Looking for nodejs + nodegyp processed native libs profiler

Tags: c++, node.js, profiling, profiler

I've used **valgrind** with **callgrind** for C++. This work great.

Then tried similiar approach using **nodegrind** for node.js. Not so great - tons of calls are missing, source cannot be located (is it just my poor configuration?). And there is no guarantee that this will ever work with C++ calls, at all. I'm now experimenting with **nodetime**, but the situations seems rather grim.

T's the reason behind this question - since node.js modules may be built with C++, how does one profile the both and the interaction thereof?

Comment: hello, I'm curious as to why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented with profiler, node-spy, nodetime, valgrind/cachegrind/nodegrind, oprofiler, systemtap, dtrace, dtrace4linux... Some worked but for node.js only (profiler was simple and good). Some had potential, but apparently didn't work well or at all on my Ubuntu (dtrace4linux, systemtap).

All in all I went for VTune. This worked brilliantly on my virtualized Ubuntu ;)